# Задача используя цикл for

Tags: python

Решаю задачу можно где можно использовать только цикл for.

При вводе большого числа  в d(сколько драконов было всего), код долго считает и сайт с проверкой решения выводит ошибку, не понимаю как это можно исправить.

«Раз дракон. Два дракон. Три дракон», — считала принцесса. У нее была бессонница, а считать барашков ей надоело еще в девять лет.

Впрочем, считать драконов просто так тоже было скучно, поэтому она развлекалась как могла. Этой ночью она представляла, что все посчитанные драконы явились сюда, чтобы ее украсть, а она отбивается от них, как может. Каждого k-ого дракона она била сковородкой по морде. Каждому l-ому — прищемляла хвост балконной дверью. Каждому m-ому — наступала на лапу острым каблучком. Наконец, каждому n-ому она грозила позвать мамочку, и он в ужасе ретировался.

Скольким воображаемым драконам успела нанести моральный или физический ущерб принцесса, если всего она насчитала d драконов?

Входные данные
Входные данные содержат целые числа k, l, m, n и d, каждое число в отдельной строке (1 ≤ k, l, m, n ≤ 10, 1 ≤ d ≤ 105).

Выходные данные
Выведите количество пострадавших драконов.

```
k=int(input())
l=int(input())
m=int(input())
n=int(input())
d=int(input())
spis=list()
if k==1 or l==1 or m==1 or n==1 or d==1:
    print(d)
elif k>d or l>d or m>d or n>d:
    print(0)
else:
    for i in range(1, d+1):
        spis.append(i)
    for i in range(1, d+1, k):
        if i in spis:
            spis.remove(i)
    for i in range(1, d+1, l):
        if i in spis:
            spis.remove(i)
    for i in range(1, d+1, m):
        if i in spis:
            spis.remove(i)
    for i in range(1, d+1, n):
        if i in spis:
            spis.remove(i)
    print(d-len(spis))
```

Comment: А что за ошибка то?.. Прикрепите

Comment: А обязательно через фор? Можно ведь с помощью GCD  посчитать, однако быстрее будет

Comment: @MBo по формуле включения/исключения получится 4 + 6 + 4 + 1 = 15 слагаемых. Или я не умею её готовить?

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy Ну да, как-то так, я не считал.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если в вашем коде изменить `spis=list()` на `spis=set()` вы уложитесь по времени. Операции проверки значения на принадлежность и удаление элемента медленные для списка (линейные), но быстрые для множества (константные).

Однако драконов можно сосчитать без дополнительной памяти. Пересказ печальной истории на Python:

```
k = int(input()) # этих будем бить сковородой
l = int(input()) # этим щемить хвосты
m = int(input()) # этих ранить каблуками
n = int(input()) # этих запугивать мамой
d = int(input()) # сколько сосчитать драконов

# считаем ущемлённых драконов
c = 0

# i - номер дракона
for i in range(1, d + 1):
    if i % k == 0:
        # ударили сковородой
        c += 1 # одним несчастным драконом больше
        continue
    if i % l == 0:
        # прищемили хвост балконной дверью
        c += 1 # одним несчастным драконом больше
        continue
    if i % m == 0:
        # наступили на лапу острым каблучком
        c += 1 # одним несчастным драконом больше
        continue
    if i % n == 0:
        # запугали угрозами позвать маму
        c += 1 # одним несчастным драконом больше
        continue
    # этот дракон избежал насилия со стороны принцессы, не считается

# печальный результат
print(c)
```

Или короче:

```
k = int(input()) # этих будем бить сковородой
l = int(input()) # этим щемить хвосты
m = int(input()) # этих ранить каблуками
n = int(input()) # этих запугивать мамой
d = int(input()) # сколько сосчитать драконов

# считаем ущемлённых драконов
c = 0

# i - номер дракона
for i in range(1, d + 1):
    #  ударили сковородой или
    #      |         прищемили хвост балконной дверью или
    #      |             |         наступили на лапу острым каблучком или
    #      |             |             |         запугали угрозами позвать маму
    #      V             V             V             V
    #  ----------    ----------    ----------    ----------
    if i % k == 0 or i % l == 0 or i % m == 0 or i % n == 0:
        # одним несчастным драконом больше
        c += 1

# печальный результат
print(c)
```

**P.S.** Задача имеет решение за постоянное время. Нет нужды считать всех драконов, чтобы узнать сколько из них повредила принцесса. См. [формула включений-исключений](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9#%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%85).

Answer (score 1):

можно ли считать это решением решением через `for`?

```
res = len([1 for i in range(1, d + 1) if any(i % j == 0 for j in (k, l, m, n))])
```

вот только `for`:

```
res = len([1 for i in range(1, d + 1) if sum(i % j == 0 for j in (k, l, m, n)) > 0])
```

или только с 1 `for`:

```
res = sum(i % k == 0 or i % l == 0 or i % m == 0 or i % n == 0 for i in range(1, d + 1))
```